# trying to store image from vue form and send to backend laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, rest

I'm a newbie and i'm trying to create a rest project with Vue and Laravel and I have a form that allows to send an image, but when I try to store it in the db, I got an error:

> "Request failed with status code 422"
> and
> "The image must be an image"

I can't figure how to solve it, any suggestion?

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            title: undefined,
            year: undefined,
            director: undefined,
            plot: undefined,
            rating: undefined,
            image: null,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        insertedFile(e) {
            this.image = e.target.files[0];

        },
        addFilm() {

            const formData = new FormData;
            formData.set('image', this.image)
            console.log(formData.get('image'));
            // 
            axios
                .post("/api/films", {
                    title: this.title,
                    year: this.year,
                    director: this.director,
                    plot: this.plot,
                    rating: this.rating,
                    image:formData
                })
                .then((response) => {
                   console.warn(response)
                });
        },
    },
};
</script>

<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="addFilm()" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="title" v-model="title" />
        <input type="number" name="year" placeholder="year" v-model="year" />
        <input
            type="text"
            name="director"
            placeholder="director"
            v-model="director"
        />
        <input type="text" name="plot" placeholder="plot" v-model="plot" />

        <input
            type="number"
            name="rating"
            placeholder="rating"
            v-model="rating"
        />
        <input
            type="file"
            name="image"
            id="image"
            @change="insertedFile($event)"
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $request->validate([

            'title' => 'required',
            'year' => 'required',
            'plot' => 'required',
            'director' => 'required',
            'rating' => 'required',
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,svg|max:2048'

        ]);
    


            $film = new Film([
                'title' => $request->title,
                'year' => $request->year,
                'plot' => $request->plot,
                'director' => $request->director,
                'rating' => $request->rating,
                "image" => $request->file('image')->store('images', 'public')

            ]);
            $film->save();
       

        return redirect()->route('home')
            ->with('success', 'film created successfully!');
    }
```

Comment: Your validation is failing, in particular this rule: `'image' => 'image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,svg|max:2048'`

Comment: @Peppermintology  if I try to upload an image with a form in a blade template, it gives no errors and can see the path normaly in the db :/

Answer (score 0):

Try combining your payload (data) with your `formData` and setting the `content-type` header of your `axios` request to `multipart/form-data`:

```
const config = {
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
}

let data = new FormData();
data.append('title', this.title);
data.append('year', this.year);
data.append('director', this.director);
data.append('plot', this.plot);
data.append('rating', this.rating);
data.append('image', this.image);

axios.post('api/films', data, config)
.then((response) => {
    console.warn(response)
 })
 .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
 });
```

Comment: This finally works, thank you! :)

Comment: @CarolinaTronci Good stuff.  [:

Answer (score 0):

you're passing the FormData object as image.
in order to make it work, you should give axios the FormData object containing all the data you want to send.

addFilm method should look like this:

```
            const formData = new FormData;

            formData.append('image', this.image)
            formData.append('title', this.title)
            formData.append('year', this.year)
            formData.append('director', this.director)
            formData.append('plot', this.plot)
            formData.append('rating', this.rating)
            formData.append('image', this.image)

            axios
                .post("/api/films", formData)
                .then((response) => {
                   console.warn(response)
                });
```